# Java login error

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to java program. I have created a java program with login interface using eclipse and MYSQL. once I login its repeating  the login successfully message 2 or 3 times. and its opening 2 times the main interface. here is my code. looking fro the solution.

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {

                String query = "select * from xyzlibrary.user_account";

                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {

                    String username= rs.getString(1);
                    String password= rs.getString(2);

                    if (tfusername.getText().equals(username) && tfpasswordField.getText().equals(password)) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login successfull!");

                        Admin ad = new Admin();
                        ad.setVisible(true);

                        dispose();

                    }else

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect User ID or Password!");


                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
    });
    btnLogin.setBounds(125, 187, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnLogin);
```

Comment: You're checking against *every* user record in the database.  As an alternative, consider adding a `WHERE` clause to your SQL so that it only returns the one matching user record (or no records in the case of a failed login).

Comment: More than likely getting back more than 1 result. Once you verify login you should exit your while loop manually.

Answer (score 2):

Add `where` clause in your `query` because you will get all rows from your user table. Then because of `while` loop you get 2,3 or more messages and windows, depending on the number rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is far simpler to select only the relevant records of your table, by filtering on the username and password fields at the query level.

Also use a `PreparedStatement` which will take care of escaping your values, and prevent SQL injection.

The example below assumes that the relevant columns in your table are called `username` and `password`, just change them to the actual names of your columns .

```
// just change the column names to fit your table's columns
String query = "SELECT username from xyzlibrary.user_account WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

// create a PreparedStatement which will escape values correctly
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);

// replace values
st.setString(1,tfusername.getText());
st.setString(2,tfpasswordField.getText());

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();

// if the result is not empty, the login is a success
if(rs.next()){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login successfull!");

    Admin ad = new Admin();
    ad.setVisible(true);

    dispose();

}
else{

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect User ID or Password!");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is add a **return** statement after you print out the accepted login. That will solve your immediate problem. But long term, I suggest you add a **SQL WHERE** clause to your SQL Select statement

Answer (score 0):

The "login successful" message will be printed as many times as there are results in your query. So if you have 2 usernames it will get printed 2 times.

Why not move the print out of the while loop? In this way it will only get printed 1 time no matter how many results you will get.